# How to Customize iCarousel Coverflow like below in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, icarousel

I have to present a view like this in the picture :

[image]

I remember that iCarrousel project can do such things, Could Any one guide me to the right control that provide this animation?

I Tried and Got Something like this

[image]

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You need to adjust the tilt of the item views, which can be done using the `carousel:valueForOption:withDefault:` delegate method, like this:

```
- (CGFloat)carousel:(iCarousel *)carousel valueForOption:(iCarouselOption)option withDefault:(CGFloat)value
{
    if (option == iCarouselOptionSpacing)
    {
        return value * 1.5;
    }
    else if (option == iCarouselOptionTilt)
    {
        return 0.2;
    }
    return value;
}
```

The values included are just example. You'll need to tweak the title, and probably also the spacing, to avoid having the items appear to pass through each other.

Comment: Hello, can you check this please? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49303429/ios-set-opacity-of-items-in-icarousel-type-rotary

Answer (score 0):

The iCarousel repo includes several demo projects, one of which includes the option to display all the different types of Carousels it offers. It's been a while since I've used it, but I'm pretty sure one of the options is what you're after.

I suggest going through the demo programs and looking for the carousel type that matches what you want. Then there are a multitude of settings that you can adjust to customize the look of the carousel.

Comment: I have been through the demo, but unable to increase the height of the two images which are in the background, so can u suggest some method to do so.

Comment: There are settings that let you control the height of the "cylinder" it uses to display the images, the amount of perspective that's applied, and many other things. I don't remember them off the top of my head, and would have to go read the (extensive and very good) docs and experiment. The documentation on the framework is excellent. I suggest you check it out.